Overriden DataSource Bean connection gets constantly closed
I have a setup where Spring-Boot, meaning Spring-Data in the end, manages all my database connections with the default settings. No problems there. For integration-tests I overrode the DataSource, like this:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() { return new ExtendedHikariDataSource(); }

  // If you override dataSource, Spring needs the 3 other Beans to be provided too:
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    jpaProperties.put(TransactionSettings.AUTO_CLOSE_SESSION, "false");
    jpaProperties.put(MappingSettings.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY ...);
    ...
    return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), 
                               jpaProperties, null)
        .dataSource(dataSource())
        .packages("org.mypackage")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() { 
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
  }
}

The problem is now, that Spring closes the database connection after almost all operations, even a simple save. Like this:
...
// Standard Spring "CrudRepository".
@Autowired private MyCrudRepository myCrudRepository;

@Test
void testSave() {
  myCrudRepository.save(myObject);
  // Connection gets closed. Instantly, no timeouts or anything.
}

Now I constantly run into exceptions being thrown, because the connection got closed. What setting do I have to set, to tell Spring / Hibernate / JPA / etc. that I want the "normal" behavior?

**  // If you override dataSource, Spring needs the 3 other Beans to be provided too:** No you don't. Spring will still automatically configure the other beans, so no idea where you got that from. I also wonder why you extended the datasource and how you detect the closing of the connection.

@M.Deinum, well, it works w/o the extra Bean overrides, but then it complains about the missing hibernate.dialect, like "Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)".
I extended the DataSource so I can reopen it immediately after it got closed, and I set breakpoints there to find out what causes the closing.
But removing the other 3 Bean implementations is helping, it takes another route through the code then.

You don't need to override that you can just specify in your application.properties.

@M.Deinum application.yml overrides? Well, I thought so, but neither "spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect", nor "hibernate.dialect" or anything else seem to bother it. It seems to ignore the yml completely when a custom DataSource is provided.

Because those parameters don't make any sense. Use spring.jpa.database-platform or spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect. As also mentioned in the Sprng Boot documentation.

OK, for the dialect it was: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", but it still constantly closes.

What makes you think it closes.

The constant exceptions that it was closed and the operations failing because they need open connections, and also the breakpoints in the close method being constantly hit, after each small Crud operation.

The close method of what. THe close will be called and it will effectivly be returned to the pool so yes close will always be called.

The close method on the extended HikariDataSource. Which is then set to closed, which causes the exceptions. But maybe I broke that there. Thanks, I will examine that there.

The DataSource will only be closed if the application stops, which would be after your tests have run. The close on the Connection will be called after every transaction. I doubt the datasource is being closed and you are mixing things up. Post some logging output, stacktraces etc.

Thanks for all the help. But I gave up, because the behavior was too erratic with multi-threading settings. The more reasonable solution for tests would probably be to have 2 separate DataSources declared, instead of manipulating just one. Makes BlackBox testing harder, but so be it. I will investigate that in the future, when I have more available time.
